# CURSOR in sql server do not stop

Tags: sql-server, cursor

My making cursor for taking values from one table and insert into second table. there are only 35 entries to be inserted . But my cursor do not stop.
it do not stop even after one minute . i have to stop execution.
please tell my error.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Insert_Details_In_CForm_From_Orders]
as Begin

    Declare @CF_B_ID [int],
            @CF_Date [date],
            @CF_Invoice_No [int],
            @CF_Quantity [decimal](18, 2),
            @CF_Amount [decimal](18, 2),
            @CF_Tax [decimal](18, 2),
            @CF_Total_Amount [decimal](18, 2),
            @Financial_Year [nvarchar](25),
            @Quater [int]

    Select  @Financial_Year = Financial_Year,
            @Quater = Quater 
    From Company

    --Select a.O_B_ID,a.O_B_LR_Datetime,a.O_B_Bill_No,a.Total_Quantity,a.Total_Duty_Plus,a.Total_CST,a.Total_CST_Plus From Orders a , C_Form b where a.CST_TF=1 AND a.O_B_Bill_No!=b.CF_Invoice_No
    Declare @CFormCursor CURSOR
    SET @CFormCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
    FOR
        Select  a.O_B_ID as CF_B_ID,
                a.O_B_LR_Datetime as CF_Date,
                a.O_B_Bill_No as CF_Invoice_No,
                a.Total_Quantity as CF_Quantity,
                a.Total_Duty_Plus as CF_Amount,
                a.Total_CST as CF_Tax,
                a.Total_CST_Plus as CF_Total_Amount  
        From Orders a , C_Form b 
        where a.CST_TF = 1 
        AND a.O_B_Bill_No != b.CF_Invoice_No

    OPEN @CFormCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @CFormCursor 
    INTO @CF_B_ID ,@CF_Date ,@CF_Invoice_No ,@CF_Quantity  ,@CF_Amount  ,@CF_Tax  ,@CF_Total_Amount 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[C_Form] ([CF_B_ID],[CF_Date],[CF_Invoice_No],[CF_Quantity],[CF_Amount],[CF_Tax],[CF_Total_Amount],[Financial_Year],[Quater])
        VALUES(@CF_B_ID ,@CF_Date ,@CF_Invoice_No,@CF_Quantity,@CF_Amount,@CF_Tax,@CF_Total_Amount,@Financial_Year,@Quater)
        FETCH NEXT FROM @CFormCursor 
        INTO @CF_B_ID ,@CF_Date ,@CF_Invoice_No ,@CF_Quantity  ,@CF_Amount  ,@CF_Tax  ,@CF_Total_Amount 
    END
    CLOSE @CFormCursor
    DEALLOCATE @CFormCursor
End
```

Comment: Why do you need a cursor at all? why not just use `insert...select`?

Comment: But i should know where i m lagging

Comment: Also, read this article by Aaron Bertrand: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: How many records do you get when you execute the select of the cursor? You only have a 'non equality' join condition, I would expect some sort of cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the cursor processing is slow but as other contributors have hinted the old style join in your select statement might take a long time depending on the size of the 2 tables. Try changing it to

```
Select  a.O_B_ID as CF_B_ID,
                a.O_B_LR_Datetime as CF_Date,
                a.O_B_Bill_No as CF_Invoice_No,
                a.Total_Quantity as CF_Quantity,
                a.Total_Duty_Plus as CF_Amount,
                a.Total_CST as CF_Tax,
                a.Total_CST_Plus as CF_Total_Amount  
        From Orders a 
        join C_Form b on a.O_B_Bill_No = b.CF_Invoice_No
        where a.CST_TF = 1 
        AND  b.CF_Invoice_No is null
```

Comment: this join is not equivalent to the join in the question.

Comment: @Zohar. I don't think it should be. The original select seems to me that only Orders which don't appear in C_Form are of interest. So the equivalent join is an equality with the orders which don't appear in C_form being caught by the null test. A != join would cause the same problem as the original.

Comment: That's for the OP to decide. I was just stating a fact :-)